# Best way to store total count of collection - mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, count

(New to web development)

I have a website written using nodejs.

In a mongo database, I have a user table which is expected to hold 50000+ rows.

I have a webpage which needs to reflect the total number of users when it is refreshed. This need not be accurate/real time (i.e. I could refresh the total user count once every hour or few hours).

I was wondering the best practices for storing this data.

Should I run a `count()` query every time the page is refreshed? Or should I store a variable `total_users` somewhere which is refreshed via a cron job every hour or so? Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Getting number of all documents in a collection should be pretty fast, no need to cache it separately.

Comment: Even if the size of the dataset becomes much bigger later?

Comment: Yes, it's cached by mongo itself. Note the caveat: "count __all__ documents (`db.users.count()`)". Counting with condition is entirely different matter.

Comment: Okay great, thanks so much!